# How git knows about changing file name from a single blob?

Tags: git

I created a pure directory and started to track it with git and
I track `.git` directory with this command:

```
tree -C -I 'info|pack' .git/objects
```

I create a file named `readme.md` with content `hello world`  and staged this using `git add .`
git creates a blob:

```
.git/objects
└── 3b
    └── 18e512dba79e4c8300dd08aeb37f8e728b8dad
```

as far as I know, a blob knows noting about file name and there is no other git object in `.git` directory

```
├── objects
│   ├── 3b
│   │   └── 18e512dba79e4c8300dd08aeb37f8e728b8dad
│   ├── info
│   └── pack
└── refs
    ├── heads
    └── tags
```

but when I rename the file to `readyou.md` and run `git status`

```
On branch master

No commits yet

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
    new file:   readme.md

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    deleted:    readme.md

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    readyou.md
```

git is totally aware of the changes, so it should track file name somewhere if it's not the blob, where is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the internal blob storage format, and everything to do with the actual commands you ran.

In particular, you did:

```
git init
echo hello world > readme.md
git add readme.md
```

So far so good: you've had Git copy the `readme.md` file into Git's index.  Since the index doesn't actually hold copies of file data, Git had to make the internal blob object you mention; what's in the index now, if you dump it out with `git ls-files --stage` or `git ls-files --debug`, is one entry with mode `100644` (plain file), name `readme.md`, and the blob hash.

But now instead of `git mv readme.md readyou.md` or some other equivalent series of commands, you ran:

```
mv readme.md readyou.md
```

This renamed your *work-tree* copy of the file.  The file in your work-tree is managed by your operating system, not by Git.  The copy in your work-tree is not what will go into the next commit: what will go into the next commit is whatever is in Git's index.  This is entirely unchanged.

Your `git status` command works by doing the following:

1. List information about the current branch and that sort of thing.  You're currently on an *unborn* branch, or *orphan* branch (Git uses both terms for this): the name `master` is stored in `.git/HEAD` but no branch named `master` actually exists, because no commits exist yet.  So the first line of `git status` says this.
2. Compare the current commit to the index.  There is no current commit yet, so Git uses instead Git's [empty tree](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9765453/1256452) as the left-side of this comparison.  The result of the comparison is to announce that there is a new file named `readme.me` that will go into the next commit.  These are your *changes to be committed*.
3. Compare the index to the work-tree.  The index contains a file named `readme.md`, and the work-tree doesn't.  So `readme.md` is deleted.  The work-tree contains a file named `readyou.md` and the index doesn't; Git holds on to this for a moment.  The result of this comparison is to announce that the file `readme.md` is deleted, but these are your *changes not staged for commit*.
4. Finally, since there are work-tree files that is not in the index, Git filters this list through the `.gitignore` entries.  (Technically this actually happens while scanning the work-tree: there's no point putting files into a list, then knocking them out, when Git can just avoid putting them in at all.)  Since there are no `.gitignore` entries, Git *doesn't* shut up about this: it prints these files' names, as *untracked files*.

The key to all of this is to realize that Git has this extra copy<sup>1</sup> of each file in Git's index, and that `git commit` will build the new commit *from* the index.  Git will not even look at your work-tree here.  It's what is in the index that matters.  The `git status` command does not show you what's in the index; instead, it shows you what's *different* in the index, twice: once as compared to the current commit (or the empty tree in this special state), and once as compared to your work-tree, on the assumption that you can actually see what's in your work-tree.

If the index matches the work-tree, there's nothing you can copy *from* the work-tree, *to* the index, to change it.  So that's not interesting, and the last two `git status` output sections—changes not staged, and untracked files—are empty.  If the index matches the current *commit*, there's no reason to make a new commit, so that's not interesting, and the changes-staged-for-commit section of output is empty.

---

<sup>1</sup>Again, the index really holds (mode, name, blob-hash) tuples.  It also has a bunch of cache data, which is why it's sometimes called the *cache*, though these days, *cache* is supposed to be reserved for the in-memory data structure that Git builds by reading the `.git/index` file.  Because you *use* the index to "stage" updated files for committing, the index is also called the *staging area*.

---

#### Note that `git mv` is not special in any way

If you use `git mv readme.md readyou.md`, Git:

- renames the work-tree file, and
- rips out the old `readme.md` index entry and puts in a `readyou.md` entry instead.

`git status` will now just say that there is a new `readyou.md` file, ready to be committed.  But suppose you actually commit the `readme.md` file first.  Now `git status` will say that there is a *rename* ready to be committed.

Technically, all that will happen if you make a second commit is that the second commit will have a file named `readyou.md` and *not* have a file named `readme.md`.  It's Git's difference engine—the program you can invoke with `git diff`, that `git status` also invokes, and other Git commands use—that decides that this file was "renamed".

If, instead of `git mv`, you run:

```
mv readme.md readyou.md
git add readme.md readyou.md
```

the separate `git add` step here will *remove* `readme.md` from the index and copy `readyou.md` into the index (again see footnote 1—it will really just keep the existing blob object).  Oddly, `git add path/to/file` *removes* *`path/to/file`* from the index if it's there in the index *and* not there in the work-tree.  The way to make sense of this is to realize that `git add` doesn't just mean *copy file from work-tree to index*, but instead means something simpler: *make index match work-tree*.  The "match" in the case of a renamed or removed file is to remove the old name.

When Git is comparing two commits, or one commit and the index, or the index and your work-tree, or whatever, Git will detect a rename only under certain conditions.  These include:

- The rename detector must be *enabled*.  When you run `git diff` you can turn it on manually with `-M` or `--find-renames`.  It defaulted to *off* in old versions of Git, and switched to *on* by default in Git 2.9.  You can configure your own private default using the `diff.renames` configuration knob.
- The file's *content* must either match exactly—an exact match is fast for Git—or be "similar enough".  This similarity is expressed as a percentage: an exact match is 100% similar, and a file with no bytes in common is 0% similar.  Files that are not identical but do have some bytes in common, as determined by a quick and dirty file scanner, are some percentage similar: more than zero, less than 100.  When using `--find-renames` or `-M` you can set the similarity threshold.  The default is 50%.  Files that aren't at least 50, or whatever other number, percent similar are considered "not renamed".
- For Git to detect a rename, there must be a file on the "left side" that is just not there on the "right side", and vice versa.  For instance, in this case, the left side—the first commit—would have a file named `readme.md`, but the right side—the current index content—would not.  The right side has `readyou.md` but the left side does not.  Git *pairs up* left and right side files that have the *same name*.  Any files left over, i.e., not paired at this point, are candidates for rename detecting.
- When using `git diff`, there's something else you can do with the `-B` (break-pairings) option.  You can't do this with `git status` so we won't go into any further detail.

The `git status` command has the rename detector turned on and set to 50% by default.  In older versions of Git there is no way to change this, but Git 2.18 added `status.renames` as an option, and made it follow `diff.renames` as a default if you don't have it set.  So now `diff.renames` also controls `git status`, unless you set both `diff.renames` *and* `status.renames`.

The point of all this verbiage is that `git mv` isn't really *special*.  It just takes care of two rename operations at once: one in the index, and one in your work-tree.  If you forget, just use `git add` to remove the old name and add the new one.  The effect is exactly the same: the *next* commit you will make, as stored right now in Git's index, is now updated correctly.

Comment: thanks a lot, you explained way more than I expected.